# MSMQ negative acknowledgment messages not being sent while positive acknowledgment messages are

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msmq

Hi I have this snippet of code that works perfectly fine when messages reach their intended queue (Messages end up in the queue and acknowledgment messages end up in another queue indicating the messages have reached their destination).

For some reason, it does not work as intended when messages do not reach their queue (the acknowledgment messages never get sent to their queue).

I have been testing this by simply deleting the private queue that the regular messages are intended to reach if that is of any help.

```
Message message = new Message();
message.TimeToReachQueue = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(m_timeToReachQueue);
message.AcknowledgeType =  AcknowledgeTypes.FullReachQueue;
// set admin queue for receiving (negative) acknowledgements of delivery                
message.AdministrationQueue = new MessageQueue(m_adminQueueName);
message.ResponseQueue = new MessageQueue(m_adminQueueName);

//This is just for populating the message body and label then finally sending it
message.Label = RenderLabel(loggingEvent);       
using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream, new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false, true));
        base.RenderLoggingEvent(writer, loggingEvent);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        message.BodyStream = stream;

        m_queue.Send(message);
        m_queue.Close();
    }
```

Comment: If you add UseDeadLetterQueue, do you see messages appearing in the DLQ? "Tracking down where your MSMQ messages have gone" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/05/26/tracking-down-where-your-msmq-messages-have-gone.aspx

Comment: I too faced the same problem and haven't found a solution yet. According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/07/31/checking-if-msmq-queues-exist-is-hard-work-so-should-you-bother.aspx - "a negative acknowledgement (NACK) will be returned to the administration queue with a class of  "The destination queue does not exist." (MQMSG_CLASS_NACK_BAD_DST_Q)". But that does not seem to happen in reality.